# Inject variable values into placeholder configuration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

**Objectives**

To run through a file with a single command and replace the placeholder variables in the configuration file with variables defined in the shell script.

**Requirements**

- I don't want to source the config file since I have tried that and it doesnt work.
- A single command to work for any placeholder variables (i.e both username and password in this example)

**Current attempt**

*deploy.sh*

```
USERNAME="tom"
PASSWORD="secret"

sed 's/\$PLACEHOLDER_/\$/g' test.conf
```

*test.conf*

```
deploy="$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME"
credentials="$PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD"
```

**Problem**

- Currently it changes "$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME" into "$USERNAME"
- I want it to change "$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME" into "tom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[="]' 'FNR==NR {a["\$PLACEHOLDER_" $1]=$3;next} 
               $3 in a {print $1 "=\"" a[$3] "\""}' deploy.sh test.conf 
deploy="tom"
credentials="secret"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I think this is writing deploy.sh into test.conf but what I actually want to do is overwrite test.conf with the values of the placeholder variables found in deploy.sh

Comment: This will print changed `test.conf` to stdout. You can then do: `awk -F '[="]' 'FNR==NR {a["\$PLACEHOLDER_" $1]=$3;next} $3 in a {print $1 "=\"" a[$3] "\""}' deploy.sh test.conf > _tmp && mv _tmp test.conf` to get changed values in `test.conf`